# Connection between z-scores and a non-standard normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

If you have a non-standard normal distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$, and you're interested the relative likelihood that $x=x$, is there a way to use the z score $\frac{x'}{\sigma}$ with the PDF of the standard normal distribution in the same way you could if you were interested in $\Pr(x < x')$. Of course, I am not interested in explicitly solving $\Pr(x=x')$, but I am interested in the relative likelihood of $x'$ as you vary $\sigma^2$ to answer a question like "if I have two non-standard normal distributions with different variance and I observe $x'$, which distribution is more likely for that to have come from?"

Comment: $P(X = x) = 0$ for all $x$

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I am still interested in the relative likelihood of x' as you change the variance.

Comment: Hint: for any IID sample and parameter $\sigma$, let $L(x_1,\dotsc, x_n;\sigma^2)=\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i;\sigma^2)$ where $f$ is the PDF of $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. Compute the ratio $\Lambda = L(x_1,\dotsc, x_n;\sigma_0^2)/L(x_1,\dotsc, x_n;\sigma_1^2)$. Find a region $(-\infty, k]$ such that $\Lambda\leq k$, and then...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the $z-$transform of any normally distributed random variable has a standard normal distribution.

So, if you have observed $x'$ from a distribution with $\mu=0$ then the likelihood function of that single observation if we assume it has variance $\sigma^2$ is:

$$L(\sigma;x')=\Phi\left(\frac{x'}{\sigma}\right)$$

We usually work with Log-likelihood $\ell(\sigma^2;x')$, which we then maximize:

$$\ell(\sigma^2;x') = -\frac12 \left[ \ln(2\pi)+\ln(\sigma^2)+\frac{(x')^2}{\sigma^2}\right]$$

Taking derivative we get:

$$\frac{d}{d \sigma^2}\ell(\sigma^2;x') = -\frac12\left[\frac{1}{\sigma^2}-\frac{(x')^2}{\sigma^4}\right] = 0 \implies \frac{(x')^2}{\sigma^4}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \implies (x')^2=\sigma^2 \implies \widehat{\sigma} = x'$$

Which agrees with the maximum likelihood estimator for $n=1$ for a normal distribution.

If you have two simple hypotheses: $H_0:\sigma=a,\; H_1:\sigma=b$ you can form the log-likelihood ratio $\Lambda$ to compare them:

$$\Lambda(H_0,H_1) =\frac{-\frac12 \left[ \ln(2\pi)+\ln(a^2)+\frac{(x')^2}{a^2}\right]}{-\frac12 \left[ \ln(2\pi)+\ln(b^2)+\frac{(x')^2}{b^2}\right]}$$

Again, it's easier to work with the log-likelihood ratio $\ln(\Lambda(H_0,H_1)) := \lambda(H_0,H_1)$

$$\lambda(H_0,H_1) = -\frac12 \left[ \ln(2\pi)+\ln(a^2)+\frac{(x')^2}{a^2}\right] - \left(-\frac12 \left[ \ln(2\pi)+\ln(b^2)+\frac{(x')^2}{b^2}\right]\right)$$

Simplifying, we get:

$$\lambda(H_0,H_1) \propto \left[\ln(b^2)+\frac{(x')^2}{b^2}\right] - \left[ \ln(a^2)+\frac{(x')^2}{a^2}\right]=\left[\ln(b^2) - \ln(a^2) \right]+(x')^2\left[\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right]$$

Now $\lambda(H_0,H_1) > 0 \implies H_0$ which will happen when:

$$\left[\ln(b^2) - \ln(a^2) \right]+(x')^2\left[\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right]>0 \implies \left[\ln(b^2) - \ln(a^2) \right]>-(x')^2\left[\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right] \implies \frac{\left[\ln(b^2) - \ln(a^2) \right]}{\left[\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right]} > -(x')^2 \implies \frac{a^2b^2\left[\ln(a^2) - \ln(b^2) \right]}{a^2-b^2} < (x')^2$$